# sys.stdout.write and \r carriage return not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, carriage-return

I was following a little tutorial and after much research, I can't figure out why the given code doesn't print on the same line. I copied it directly, so it should work.

```
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write('29 seconds remaining')
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('\r28 seconds remaining')
```

Output is:

```
29 seconds remaining
28 seconds remaining
```

Final output should be:

```
28 seconds remaining
```

Comment: And what is the console you are using? `\r` doesn't work in IDLE, for example.

Comment: I am using PyScripter

Comment: I guess the PyScripter console also doesn't support `\r` carriage returns.

Comment: So is there a way to output and then update the output line in PyScripter? This seems to be the mainstream method.

Comment: @macdonjo: On POSIX, you could try [`blessings`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/): it allows to format and move the text easily. It might work on Windows if used with [`colorama`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama/)

Comment: It does work with Python3 without using `flush()`.
With Python2 you need to `sys.stdout.flush()` each time you print `"\r"` for updates to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the "\r" at the end of the line, not at the front. Like this:

```
 sys.stdout.write("%s[%s%s] %2i/%i\r" % (variables go here))
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: In case I finish the display and want to start a new line (for the same type of display), how to make it work?----oh never mind, I see I can use '\n'. Just leave the comment here so some other people can see.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out solutions that seemed to work for others with the same setup like me, I had to find out the hard way that **carriage return sequences are parsed by the shell that outputs the printed string** (please correct me here if not precise enough). I started getting closer to the solution when i realised that the windows command prompt (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe) actually interpreted the carriage return as expected, but the PyScripter IDE did not. Then I realised that the PyScripter developers new about this, but did not want to spend the effort of mimicking the cmd.exe behaviour.

Hope this puts fellow developers in the right direction and will save some time.